# Simplify the following indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$3^{x+4} * 5^{x+7} * 15^{2x-1}$

I tried it in this way:

$3^{x+4}*5^{x+1}*(3*5)^{2x-1}$

Then:

$3^{x+4}*5^{x+1}*3^{2x-1}*5^{2x-1}$

And what about next?

Comment: A start:  $3^{x+4}\cdot 3^{2x-1}=3^{(x+4)+(2x-1)}=3^{3x+3}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write as $3^{x+4}*3^{2x-1}*5^{x+1}*5^{2x-1}$ (using the commutative property of multiplication) and then use the rule that $b^n*b^m = b^{n+m}$.